How to volume mount entire json file in helm to be accessible from container?
I have a json file called example.json
I have a docker image (bento/benthos) that is deployed using helm and needs to find that file like so:
input:
  file:
    paths: ["./example.json"]
    codec: lines

I can't seem to find a way to mount the entire json file so that the image can find it

The Kubernetes cluster can't see files on your local system; you need to inject a copy of the file into a ConfigMap or a similar in-cluster resource.  Accessing Files Inside Templates in the Helm documentation talks about how Helm can read the file.  Do you have an existing ConfigMap resource, and an existing .Files.Get template call?

You can put the content of the json file into a ConfigMap and then use that to mount it on a Pod's container.
Here is the official howto. In this howto you'll get to see how this works and once you understand it you'll need to template it with Helm.
